# .click() jQuery function works for one ID but not variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in my *js* file and basically what I want to test out is, if the user clicks on a certain button (which has ID of admin).

I want it to bring up a `closeButton` which is *png* image and then when the user clicks this again it should disappear. To test of the button functions are responsive I have put alerts in the functions.

Clicking on the initial button works, the function finds the corresponding ID, makes the `alert("jQuery Worked")` line and brings up the `closeButton` image.

However when I click on the close button nothing happens (we expect here that the `alert("hiii")` would work but it doesn't. I have looked online and found that my code needed to be in a `$(document).ready(function() {}` function which it is but it isn't working. I also tried to use the ID of the image to make the `closeButton` image disappear but that didn't work either. So I have tried just using the `$closeButton` variable which I thought for usre should work but doesn't. Why?

**.js file**

```
var $closeButton = $("<img>");
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#admin").click(function (event) {
        var $overlay = $("<div id='overlay'> </div>");
        var $closeButton = $("<img class='classMe' id='closeButtonID' src='https://s23.postimg.org/ouup1ib6z/close_button.png'></img>");
        $("body").append($overlay);
        $overlay.append($closeButton);  

        alert("jQuery worked");
    });

    $closeButton.click(function() {
        alert("hiiii");
    });
});
```

Comment: You fill the variable _before_ the document is ready. Most likely it is empty, so holds _no_ element.

Comment: Try putting var $closeButton = $("<img>"); inside $(doucment).ready function.

Comment: The second time you try to fill it is _inside_ the handler function, so inside that function scope. The value does not exist outside that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you looking for Event delegation.

> Event delegation refers to the process of using event propagation
>   (bubbling) to handle events at a higher level in the DOM than the
>   element on which the event originated. It allows us to attach a single
>   event listener for elements that exist now or in the future. Inside
>   the Event Handling Function.

```
$(document).on('click', '#closeButtonID', function() {
     alert('hiii');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#admin").click(function (event) {
      var $overlay = $("<div id='overlay'></div>");
      var $closeButton = $("<img id='closeButtonID' src='https://s23.postimg.org/ouup1ib6z/close_button.png'></img>");
      $("body").append($overlay);
      $overlay.append($closeButton);  

      alert("jQuery worked");
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#closeButtonID', function() {
      alert('hi');
    });
});
```

Comment: This would change anything, because `$closeButton.click` would still  registered the callback to  the element created by `$("<img>")` and this element is never added to the DOM. The OP either needs to use event delegation, or move the `$closeButton.click(function() {` inside of the `$("#admin").click(function (event) {`

Comment: You should add back the `var` in front of the `$closeButton`, because otherwise the global scope is polluted unnecessarily. Beside that an explanation what you changed ans why should be used instead of a `Do this:`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good way to do this but it's a different way to solve the problem , Hope it will help you :

```
var $closeButton = $("<img>");
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#admin").click(function (event) {
        var $overlay = $("<div id='overlay'> </div>");
        var $closeButton = $("<img class='classMe' id='closeButtonID' src='https://s23.postimg.org/ouup1ib6z/close_button.png'></img>");
        $("body").append($overlay);
        $overlay.append($closeButton);  

        alert("jQuery worked");
   close();
    });
  function close(){
    $('#closeButtonID').click(function() {
        alert("hiiii");
    });
}
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lx1ceufo/)

Comment: How should this solve the problem? The `$closeButton` in the `close` function holds the `$("<img>")` and not the `$("<img class='classMe' id='closeButtonID' src='https://s23.postimg.org/ouup1ib6z/close_button.png'></img>")` so the problem will be the same.

Comment: At the time I wrote my first comment your answer was `$closeButton.click` and not `$('#closeButtonID').click`. After I wrote my comment you changed your answer to be `$('#closeButtonID').click` and this will indeed work.

Comment: I made a Small mistake , Edited now.